# Getting 404 by using Laravel routes - rewrite not working

Tags: laravel, apache, mod-rewrite, routes, xampp

I'm using Laravel-5 framework and created the following route in the routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

After navigating to `myapp.dev/test` I get an Error 404:

*Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.*

Navigating to `myapp.dev/index.php/test` works fine. So, looks like rewrite_mod is not working.

I'm using XAMP/Apache and rewrite_module is enabled in **httpd.conf**:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

My larvavel's public folder contains a **.htaccess** file with following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    #DirectoryIndex index.php

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The **httpd-vhost** configuration looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@mail.com
    DocumentRoot "s:/_dev/myapp/public"
    ServerName myapp.dev
    <Directory "s:/_dev/myapp/public">
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        #Options Indexes        
    </Directory>    
    ErrorLog "logs/myapp.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myapp.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas what I missed?

Thanks

Comment: did you restart apache? Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Yes, i restarted the server. Unfortunately, I did not found a solution in your linked post.

Comment: It might be a shorter way to migrate your project to vagrant/Laravel homestead. You will be working way easier!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sounds cool. I will have a look. But if somebody have a solution to my issue it would be great, anyway :) Because I probably will run into such an issue on productive server side later.

Comment: Have you tried to add `AllowOverride All` inside `<Directory "s:/_dev/myapp/public">` in httpd-vhost configuration ? Don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: Yes I tried it. This will lead to a 403 (Access Forbidden). After reading the article posted in answer of Josh I thought it might have something to do with this .dev issue (in newer browsers it's only possible to use .dev only with https due to HSTS hosts entry). But I also tried to use a completely arbitrary TLD. Still 403 after AllowOverride All.

Answer (score 1):

I can not see any issues with our code however it could be a browser issue.

Have a look at this article which goes through the changes to browsers that cause issues with .dev domains.

https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Very interesting article. But unfortunately this does not seem to be my issue (not yet ;) ). After reading this article I tried to use a completely arbitrary gTLD. I also tried it in several browsers including Chrome, Firefox, IE, Vivaldi (Chromium). Same issue.